# Altering table type with no constraint check

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, user-defined-types

I have a table type declared and it is referenced in many stored procedures .

Now I want to add a column to that table type .

Since sql server wont allow altering a table type . I need to drop and recreate it . But while dropping it throws error saying that it is referenced in other stored procedures . hence cant drop .

How can I proceed  without dropping stored procedures ?

Answer (score 0):

Script out all the SPs that are using the table type.

```
select o.name, o.type, m.definition
from sys.sql_modules m
join sys.objects o on o.object_id=m.object_id
where m.definition like '%tbl_type%'
```

You're better off not using the definition shown and using just the name and scripting it using SSMS from the object browser.

- Drop them.
- Drop the table type.
- Create it including the new column.
- Recreate the stored procedures.
- Test.